# Django filter by number of ForeignKey and less than a month in DateField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class MovieHistory(models.Model):
    watched_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
```

I want to get up to 15 movies that were watched the most in the last 30 days. So far I have this:

`Movie.objects.filter(time__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=30))`

How do you filter again, and order them by movie count? I know that I can filter the first 15 results like this: `[:15]`, but I don't know how to order by the amount of movies in that model, and only pick one of each (so I don't have repeated MovieHistories with the same movies on each one).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Annotation is likely the best approach:

```
from django.db.models import Count
most_watched = Movie.objects.all().annotate(num_watched = Count('watched_by')).order_by('-num_watched')[:15]
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe this is on the way to the answer. Please let me know if it works! You may need to replace `count('watched_by')` by `Count('watched_by_id')` or whatever the field name is in your database (check with `./manage.py sql your_appname`).

Hope this helps!

For more on using these annotations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: +1, But it should be `-num_watched` - OP needs the most watched.

Comment: If I append that (`annotate`) after my `filter`) it gives me an error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'annonate'`. Is it possible to chain those methods somehow?

Comment: I believe you must annotate first, then filter.